# how can send http request and get its information in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TCPClient2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect number of args, exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String host_address = args[0];
        String resource = args[1];

        Socket socket =null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        int port=80;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(host_address,port);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Unknown host");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch  (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No I/O");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        try {
            String request_line = "GET " + resource + " HTTP/1.1";
            String host_header = "Host: " + host_address;
            out.println(request_line);
            out.println(host_header);
            out.println(); // blank line = end of request header

            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error during communication");
            System.exit(-1);
        }try {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot close the socket");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

hello ,i have just started learning java network programming, i tried to send a http request and i was expecting getting its information but it returns "No I/O" all the time but it connects to server . Can any one tell where do i make mistake ?

Comment: Print the exception stacktrace, it will give you more information than "No I/O"

Comment: So there is nothing with wrong my code ,right ?

Comment: it says out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); these are null. but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace...

Comment: @m0skit0: It's hopeless because he's catching the exception and throwing away all the exception information.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions if you are not going to do anything sensible with them, instead just propagate them up. You've caught the IOException, ignored what it's message is, and then continued execution as if nothing is wrong.

Comment: u mean should i debug it ? i didnt get what should i post .

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace()` as the first line on your catch blocks to print the exception stacktrace, and post it in your question. You should always print (or better, log) the exception stacktraces, they contain useful information on why and where the exception happened.

Comment: i see i didnt know about it , i will thank you